# Remove :hover styles on click

Tags: jquery, css, removeclass

I have a jsFiddle that I am working with: http://jsfiddle.net/aL7Xe/77/

It all works great, I just need the blue hover to go away when the arrow is clicked, then to come back after you click off of it.

Trying to achieve it with:

```
$(this).removeClass('a:hover');
```

Comment: `a:hover` isn't a class, and you can't remove the `:hover` *pseudo-class* anyway; you need to override it with other styles. Try using `:active` for this; JavaScript shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Also, please read the tag wiki for [tag:jsfiddle] next time =)

Comment: thanks minitech. Obviously I'm new to this. I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the effect you want by setting a `:hover` pseudo-class for `.menutoggle`. Try this:

```
.menutoggle, .menutoggle:hover {
    background: grey;
    }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aL7Xe/79/)

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. It looks perfect on jsfiddle, but when I put it on my site, the jQuery doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions? [live preview](http://beattrack.net/test.php)

Comment: I took a look at your page source and it looks like you have what I believe are [zero width spaces](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) in your code. After I removed them your page worked for me. I saw the characters at the end lines 33, 50, and 66, as well as the beginning of line 52. I don't know how they got there, but I would recommend using an appropriate text editor to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

```
a:active{
    background:transparent;
}
```

In your CSS?